# SSLError when fetching url with python requests

Tags: python, ssl, request

I'm trying to get [a web](https://www.weathermod-bg.eu/wr/img_data.php?srs=DCE) via Python requests (version 2.25.1), and I get the following error:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.weathermod-bg.eu', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /wr/
img_data.php?srs=DCE (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_SIGNATURE_TYPE] wrong signature type (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

I have tried with and without the `verify` parameter, i.e.

```
r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
```

This command also fails. However I can get the url from a browser without problems, so it does not seem to be a connection issue.

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: In short: the magic is in reducing the security level. It's not trivial to do so though - see the linked question for instructions.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> import requests 
>>> url = 'https://www.weathermod-bg.eu' 
>>> r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
```

i dont see any problem with this.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be computer-dependent. It fails in my current computer bot not in others, but still from the same machine where this fails, I can get the web via a regular browser. Any guess how to debug the issue?